# How to ouput the log of Apache Mina SSHD?

Tags: java, apache, log4j

I am building a demo base on Apache Mina SSHD, and i import log4j by maven and config log4j,the configuration of log4j like this:

```
# priority  :debug<info<warn<error
```

## you cannot specify every priority with different file for log4j

log4j.rootLogger=debug,stdout,info,debug,warn,error

## console

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern= [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a}]:%p %l%m%n

## info log

log4j.logger.info=info

log4j.appender.info=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.info.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'

log4j.appender.info.File=./src/com/hp/log/info.log

log4j.appender.info.Append=true

log4j.appender.info.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.info.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.info.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [Thread: %t][ Class:%c >> Method: %l ]%n%p:%m%n

## debug log

log4j.logger.debug=debug

log4j.appender.debug=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.debug.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'

log4j.appender.debug.File=./src/com/hp/log/debug.log

log4j.appender.debug.Append=true

log4j.appender.debug.Threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.debug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.debug.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [Thread: %t][ Class:%c >> Method: %l ]%n%p:%m%n

## warn log

log4j.logger.warn=warn

log4j.appender.warn=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.warn.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'

log4j.appender.warn.File=./src/com/hp/log/warn.log

log4j.appender.warn.Append=true

log4j.appender.warn.Threshold=WARN

log4j.appender.warn.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.warn.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [Thread: %t][ Class:%c >> Method: %l ]%n%p:%m%n

## error

log4j.logger.error=error

log4j.appender.error = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.error.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'

log4j.appender.error.File = ./src/com/hp/log/error.log

log4j.appender.error.Append = true

log4j.appender.error.Threshold = ERROR

log4j.appender.error.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.error.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [T

I have expected that the log of apache mina sshd will be displayed on the console,but nothing came out when the project run, how can i see the log of apache mina sshd?

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me and will work for you as well.

```
# File appender
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.logfile.File=C:\\logs\\mina.log
log4j.appender.logfile.Append=true
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=10

# Direct all messages there
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logfile
log4j.logger.org.apache.sshd=DEBUG
```